# How to specify the output to predict in Keras Sequential using Pandas

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am just a beginner in keras and I am trying to learn regression.
I have a sample data like this

```
      Type  Price    EPS   Worth     PE
11     1    309  42.57  174.31   7.54
12     1    246  15.48  166.85  21.06
13     1    245  16.51  129.41  15.75
14     1    214  14.45  147.11  15.86
15     1    213  11.71  137.87  19.98
```

I am trying to Predict the price. So what have I done till now is created a Sequential Model like this

```
def build_model():
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Dense(12,activation='relu',input_shape=(4,)))
    model.add(Dense(8,activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam',metrics=['mae','mse'])

    return model
```

And then tried to predict the values like this

```
example_batch = yo[:5]
model = build_model()
model.summary()
example_result = model.predict(example_batch)
```

`yo` is this dataframe without the `price`

```
    Type    EPS   Worth     PE
11     1  42.57  174.31   7.54
12     1  15.48  166.85  21.06
13     1  16.51  129.41  15.75
14     1  14.45  147.11  15.86
15     1  11.71  137.87  19.98
```

My model predicted the values but it is not the Price. So my question is how do I specify the model to Predict `Price` on the basis of all other information.